# Create a form in Django with hundreds of check boxes without hitting the URL length limit in IE8

Tags: django, url, internet-explorer-8, django-forms

I have a form that needs to have hundreds of check boxes, but if a user selects all of them the resulting URL is so long that IE8 truncates it at about 2000 characters.

The current implementation creates URLs like:

```
http://example.com?c_$id1=on&c_$id2=on&c$id3=on...etc.
```

Basically, every check box has an ID, and that ID is sent as a parameter to the URL.

I want to change the URLs to be like this instead, with pipe-separated values:

```
http://example.com?c=$id1|$id2|$id3|$id4...etc.
```

Client-side, this is easy because I already submit the form with JavaScript, but server-side I want to avoid doing too much crazy work in my Django form, which currently has these checkboxes constructed as a couple hundred `BooleanFields`.

What's the best way to reverse the pipe-separated values in the Django form so it works smoothly?

Couple other notes:

1. I can't change the parameters to be any shorter.
2. I can't just send a post request, I need the URLs to be bookmarkable.
3. I can't get rid of the IE8 users...yet.

Comment: Have you considered making a redirection?

Comment: Wouldn't work: You'd have to send the user to the too-long URL at some point, and IE8 would truncate it.

Comment: Ok, that's for a regular redirection, but you could do a url reverse server side, without the client noticing...

Comment: Ah. So, send the user to the pipe separated URL, and server-side redirect that URL to the checkbox version? Seems hackish, no?

Comment: You might look into: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shorten/0.2.2

Comment: Qualifying my comment as hackish seems quite ironic compared to what you are trying to accomplish! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution yesterday after posting. It's somewhat lame, but from the user's perspective everything seems to work well.

1. Add a field to the form for c, and set it to have a hidden widget:

   `c = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())`
2. Add the hundreds of checkboxes to the form in its init method using a loop and a DB query:

   ```
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       COURTS = Court.objects.filter(in_use=True).values_list('courtUUID', 'short_name')
       for court in COURTS:
           self.fields['court_' + court[0]] = forms.BooleanField(
               label=court[1],
               required=False,
               initial=True,
               widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'checked': 'checked'})
           )
   ```
3. Pull the two together by converting the value of the `c` field back into the checkboxes in the clean method:

   ```
   def clean(self):
       # Convert the value in the court field to the various court_* fields
       court_str = cleaned_data.get('c')
       if court_str:
           court_ids = court_str.split(' ')  # Using a pipe here will suck on IE and Chrome (but not FF)
           for id in court_ids:
               cleaned_data['court_%s' % id] = True
   ```
4. In your template show the checkboxes to your users, but use JavaScript to populate the hidden field (`c`) in your GET parameters.

This solution seems to be working on our live site and has the nice advantage of working even if the user doesn't have javascript enabled or if the use an old URL (the old checkboxes still work).

The part I hate about this is that I'm hacking the heck out of the Django form, and it's a bit of an injustice to them. Happy to hear a better solution though.